# Groupby DatetimeIndex month

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, python-datetime

I'm trying to groupby respective month over a span of years but to no avail. For e.g. Group all the Januarys from 2011 - 2013 together. Group all the Febs together.

**Partial Dataset:**

```
Date
2011-01-01    161
2011-02-01    117
2011-03-01    239
2012-01-01    289
2012-02-01    294
2012-03-01    378
2013-01-01    383
2013-02-01    361
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Date
2011-01-01    161
2012-01-01    117
2013-01-01    239
2011-02-01    289
2012-02-01    294
2013-02-01    378
2011-03-01    383
2012-03-01    361
```

**Attempted:**

Date is DatetimeIndex

```
df = df.groupby([df.index.year],[df.index.month])
```

*Output: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'*

Comment: `df = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month])`?

Comment: @DanielMesejo yes! it works now! Do you want to put that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Just added it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing two lists, pass one list with two elements, for example:

```
df = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month])
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try `argsort`

```
df=df.iloc[df.index.month.argsort()]
df
2011-01-01    161
2012-01-01    289
2013-01-01    383
2011-02-01    117
2012-02-01    294
2013-02-01    361
2011-03-01    239
2012-03-01    378
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```